# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException working with Loaders

Tags: android, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager, android-loader

i get this Exception

> 06-26 15:49:43.390: E/AndroidRuntime(1337): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

This cursor retrieve 2 columns although i am use the same database with Quick Search box and it display data from 3 columns ,the problem is this cursor retrieve two columns although provider below retrieve Data from  3 columns

- this code snippet where i get data from cursor

  ```
   @Override
   public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle data) {
   Uri uri = SuggestProvider.CONTENT_URI;
   return new CursorLoader(getBaseContext(), uri,
          null, null , new String[]{data.getString("query")}, null);
   }
   @Override
   public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor c) {
   mCursorAdapter.swapCursor(c);
   int Id = c.getColumnIndex(database.FIELD_ID);
   int Title = c.getColumnIndex(database.SONG);
   int Artist = c.getColumnIndex(database.ARTIST);

   do {
      long thisId = c.getLong(Id);
      String thisTitle = c.getString(Title);
      String thisArtist = c.getString(Artist);
      songList.add(new Song(thisId, thisTitle, thisArtist));
    }
      while (c.moveToNext());
   }
  ```
- In this snippet provider get uri

  ```
   @Override
     public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
                  String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
      Cursor c = null;
      switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
      case SEARCH_RECORDS:
          c = table.getSongs(selectionArgs);
          break;
      case GET_RECORD:
          c = table.getSongs(selectionArgs);
          break;
      case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
          String id = uri.getLastPathSegment();
          c = table.getSong(id);
      }
     return c;
    }
  ```
- function getSongs Database table where i get Data

  ```
  public Cursor getSongs(String[] selectionArgs){

  String selection = SONG + " like ? ";

  if(selectionArgs!=null){
      selectionArgs[0] = "%"+selectionArgs[0] + "%";
  }

  SQLiteQueryBuilder queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
  queryBuilder.setProjectionMap(mAliasMap);

  queryBuilder.setTables(TABLE_NAME);

  Cursor c = queryBuilder.query(helper.getReadableDatabase(),
          new String[] { "_ID",
                  SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1 ,
                  SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2 ,
                  SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID
          } ,
          selection,
          selectionArgs,
          null,
          null,
          SONG + " asc ","1"
  );
  return c;
  ```

  }

Comment: what do you need `songList` for?

Comment: songList is ArrayList used in Adapter class

Comment: no no no, why `ArrayAdapter` when you can just use `SimpleCursorAdapter` ?

Comment: this mp3 app i have service to play songs inside service i am using adapter i cant pass simplecursoradapter to service

Comment: is this related to this error ?

Comment: pass adapter to a service? why? why do you want to pass adapter to a service?

Comment: sorry array not adapter here is code...  @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            MusicService.MusicBinder binder = (MusicService.MusicBinder)service;
            //get service
            musicSrv = binder.getService();
            //pass list
            musicSrv.setList(songList);
            musicBound = true;
        }

Comment: i should pass array contain data about songs id,artist,title to service to play songs

Comment: so pass a Cursor, whats the difference?

Comment: sorry mate i have 11 reputation i can not chat you i am a beginer

Comment: you mean i can modify my service to pass cursor  instead of array ?

Comment: pskink: is there error related to this way i am using, i see this method  should work and error is cursor retrieve 2 column instead of three  am i right ?

Comment: tell me why does the service need a cursor/array? it should only get some url of your media,  why cursor/array?

Comment: i do not remeber now i made this class 3 weeks later could you wait i will review it and tell you

Comment: inside service class i made method setList inside i pass array of songs in this service i use this list of songs to play songs play next and previous song and a lot of methods related to those implementations implements
        MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener ...and other methode that initialize songs all of this methodes need this array of songs

Comment: i only get id to be appended in uri to play gongs and title for notifications for each song played

Comment: ok by default the Cursor is positioned on the -1 position so you need to make: `while (cursor.moveToNext()) { ...`

Comment: my code is already like this look at first snippet

Comment: no, its: `do {...} while (cursor.moveToNext())`

Comment: i also tried this when you write first comment it return the same error .

Comment: no, your error "Index -1 requested" indicates you did not call moveToNext before getting the cursor values...

Comment: there is two problems .first it said i request -1 index that mean cursor does not move .second it said size equal two 1 but it should be 2 look at projection in getSongs methode . do you know the solution for second problem ?

Comment: just use DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor() and see the logcat...

Comment: sorry you are right,but there is another problem there is the FATAL exception  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: Call dumpCursor and see tge colymn names

Comment: where could you guide me or google for it

Comment: What do you mean?  Just call dumpCursor again...

Comment: sorry for my stupid questions , in my case i get cursor from loader how i call cursor again ?

Comment: Call dumpCursor() method.

Comment: where exactly in getSongs methode ?

Comment: where you have the exception

Comment: i used dumpCursor in getSongs methode also in onCreateLoader inside while ,but i see no change in logcat i passed cursor to it as param .my code dump.dumpCursor(c); . any guide please

Answer (score 0):

Why the CursorLoader has selectionArgs without selection ? did you mean to order it by "query"?

Worth a try ,sometimes ,when working with DB's ,switching the DB version which drop and recreate the table can help..

Comment: you should write this as comment not answer

Comment: i have selection in getSongs methode above

Comment: sorry ,didn't had the credit.
does mAliasMap has the same values as you wish to project ?

Comment: does mAliasMap has the same values as you wish to project ? what that mean

Comment: mAliasMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

        mAliasMap.put("_ID", FIELD_ID + " as " + "_id" );

       
        mAliasMap.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1, SONG + " as " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_1);
      
        mAliasMap.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2, ARTIST + " as " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_TEXT_2);
     
        mAliasMap.put( SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, FIELD_ID + " as " + SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID );